# Induction proof about Fibonacci numbers

Tags: solution-verification, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I am currently going through George E. Andrews Number Theory book and have gotten stuck on this induction problem ( Chapter 1, Exercise 12) :

*Prove that :*

$F_1F_2 + F_2F_3 + F_3F_4 + ... + F_{2n}F_{2n+1} = F^2_{2n+1} - 1$

In the previous exercise I have proved that :

$ F_1F_2 + F_2F_3 + F_3F_4 + ... + F_{2n-1}F_{2n} = F^2_{2n} $

My attempt:

$$\sum_{j=2}^{2n+1} F_{j-1}F_j = F_{2n+1}^2 - 1$$
$$\sum_{j=2}^{2n}F_{j-1}F_j + F_{2n}F_{2n+1} = F_{2n+1}^2 - 1$$
$$F_{2n}^2 + F_{2n}F_{2n+1} = F_{2n+1}^2 -1$$
For the basis case $ n = 1 $ it is true.
But I'm not capable of proving it for $ n = k+1 $ :
$$ F_{2(k+1)}^2 + F_{2(k+1)}F_{2(k+1)+1} = F^2_{2(k+1)+1} - 1 $$
$$F^2_{2k+2} + F_{2k+2}F_{2k+3} = F^2_{2k + 3} - 1$$
And now I'm stuck on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the proof from the previous section, you should try to use the induction hypothesis directly. Which in this case lets you do the following:

$F_1 F_2 + \ldots + F_{2k} F_{2k+1} + F_{2k+1} F_{2k+2} + F_{2k+2} F_{2k+3} = F_{2k+1}^2 - 1 + F_{2k+1} F_{2k+2} + F_{2k+2} F_{2k+3}$

From here, you can expand the $F_{2k+3}$ in the last term and use that to combine some terms usefully.